# sendmail with HTML message

Tags: python, html, mime-types, sendmail, mime-message

I am programming with Python. I already have a function that sends an email with a message and an attachment....My only problem is that I want the message to be HTML, but mine does not respect that.....

Here is the function that I'm using

```
def enviarCorreo(fromaddr, toaddr, text, file):
   msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
   msg['From'] = fromaddr
   msg['To'] = toaddr
   msg['Subject'] = 'asunto'
   msg.attach(MIMEText(text))
   #adjunto
   adjunto = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
   adjunto.set_payload(open(file, "rb").read())
   encode_base64(adjunto)
   anexo = os.path.basename(file)
   adjunto.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename= "%s"' % anexo)
   msg.attach(adjunto)
   #enviar
   server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
   server.set_debuglevel(1)
   server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, msg.as_string())
   server.quit()
   return
```

I hope you can tell me what to change or what to add so the message I send could be HTML....

I am using the "MIXED" Multipart because the HTML message will contain some images that would not be attached but would be part of the message.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace

```
msg.attach(MIMEText(text))
```

by

```
msg.attach(MIMEText(text, 'html'))
```

*(default is 'plain')*

Comment: great. Don't forget to reward me ;-)

Comment: Do you know if I put <img src="XXXX" /> into the HTML message, with the apropiate path, would it be desplay in the message???

I am trying to do this, but it only displays the X image (not found image)...

Comment: Adding charset as in MIMEText(x, y, charset='utf-8') may help a lot as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is an example on the official documentation page that sends HTML email - http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html

Comment: Thanks, I have tried with this page....my problem with it is that they import doing this "from email.mine.multipart----" which i dont know why does not work for me.....i have to do it something like this "from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart"