# How to send mail only using web.py in python?

Tags: python, html, sendmail, web.py

I have a web.py project with a notice module - the system will notice users by sending an email with HTML format .

I know how to send HTML format email in python .(Also desc in this Q [sendmail with HTML message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300860/sendmail-with-html-message)) , and also know the sendmail() funciton in web.py (version 0.37).

```
import web

web.config.smtp_server = 'smtp.gmail.com' 
web.config.smtp_port = 587                
web.config.smtp_username = 'goooooooooooooogle@gmail.com' 
web.config.smtp_password = '*********'    
web.config.smtp_starttls = True

web.sendmail('goooooooooooooogle@gmail.com',['1361877@gmail.com'],'Hello nodexy','This email is from web.py !')
```

I expect :

```
web.sendmail('goooooooooooooogle@gmail.com',['1361877@gmail.com'],'Hello nodexy', '<html><img src="hello.png"/></html>')
```

Now how can I fix this in web.py ? I'm sure I can not set the HTML string to the sendmail() function .

Comment: Do you have some exception info?

Comment: The above code is ok. But the problem is how to send HTML mail in web.py ? Maybe not use sendmail() ? Any other function ?

Comment: I got it from web.py help info.  just import web and help(web.sendmail) :) .  Thanks anyway !

Comment: If you solved it, you should post an answer to your question and then accept it. That way it will be listed as answered and other people searching for this problem will see how you did it (and you might get more upvotes!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

send html mail, add a key to headers:

```
web.sendmail(from_address, to_address, subject, msg, headers={'Content-Type':'text/html;charset=utf-8'})
```

in web.py utils.py, see _EmailMessage's prepare_message method:

```
def prepare_message(self):
    for k, v in self.headers.iteritems():
        if k.lower() == "content-type":
            self.message.set_type(v)
        else:
            self.message.add_header(k, v)

    self.headers = {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I get it from help(web.sendmail) in web.py !

```
>>> import web
>>> help(web.sendmail)
```

Help on function sendmail in module web.utils:

```
sendmail(from_address, to_address, subject, message, headers=None, **kw)
```

Sends the email message `message` with mail and envelope headers
for from `from_address_` to `to_address` with `subject`.
Additional email headers can be specified with the dictionary
`headers.

Optionally cc, bcc and attachments can be specified as keyword arguments.
Attachments must be an iterable and each attachment can be either a
filename or a file object or a dictionary with filename, content and
optionally content_type keys.

As @number23_cn 's answer, just add this key 'Content-Type' to headers .